# VueJs simple @click doesn't work inside a single file component

Tags: laravel, events, vue.js

The method defined in the component template simple doesn't fire.
When the upload button is clicked, I want the uploadFiles method to fire so I could upload the images before the user submits the form.

I just don't understand why it's not working. I also tried v-on:click="uploadFiles" and still no luck.

I'm using Laravel btw.

HTML Form

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Create a new project</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form method="post" action="/project/store">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">Subtitle</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subtitle" id="subtitle">
                      </div>
                      <div id="app">
                        <upload-project-image></upload-project-image>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sel2">Mutiple select list (hold shift to select more than one):</label>
                            <select multiple class="form-control" id="categories" name="categories[]">
                                @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Description</label>
                        <textarea name="body" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <button class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('upload-project-image', require('./components/UploadImage.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Component

```
 <template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel2">Select Project Images</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="files[]" 

        id="files" multiple>
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02">{{numberOfFiles}}</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group-append">


               <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="uploadFiles" type="button">Upload</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
          return{
            files:{},
            numberOfFiles: 0
          }
        },
        methods:{
          uploadFiles(){
            console.log("Nothing gets printed to the console");
          },
          uploadSongs(){
              const fileInput = document.querySelector( '#files' );
              const files = fileInput.files;
              this.numberOfFiles = files.length;

              for(let i=0; i < files.length; i++){
                  let formData = new FormData();
                  formData.append('files[]', files[i]);

                  axios.post( '/upload', formData ).then( ( response ) => {
                    console.log(response);
                  })

              }
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't have anything in mind, but try to make the button to be `a` tag instead of `button`, it would still look the same with the CSS classes.

Comment: You are dealing with forms. Is it possible your click is handled by the default handler? If so it can be solved by doing it like this: @click.prevent

Comment: try to add mounted hook and console log something to test if there is any problem rendering your vue compnent ?

Comment: I did everything that you guys said and none of it works. I even put the component tag outside of the form just to test if it has anything to do with the form but the click event still doesn't fire. This is very strange to me.

Comment: and yeah the function does get called if it's fired from mounted hook

Answer (score 0):

This is because of forms. In forms any click event / button will be treated as submit (page gets reloaded) until unless specifed. To stop it from submitting you can do as follows

more reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: Hello and thanks for the replay but the problem still persists even when preventing the default form event. I even tried to put the component tag outside of the form to check if it works and it doesn't. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try @click.native="uploadFiles"